# Creating a function to print out the values stored in hash table

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

I am having trouble figuring out how to print out he values I have stored in this hash table.

**Code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char word;
    char* name;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

node* first[26] = {NULL};

int main(char* name)
{

    char* names[] = { "nick", "noah", "kyle", "sam", "hugo", "batman"};


    int hashedValue = hash(name);

    insert(hashedValue, name);
}

int hash(const char* buffer)
{
    return tolower(buffer[0]) - 'a';
}

void insert(int key, const char* buffer)
{
    // try to instantiate node to insert word
    node* newptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newptr == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // make a new pointer
    strcpy(newptr->word, buffer);
    newptr->next = NULL;

    // check for empty list
    if (first[key] == NULL)
    {
       first[key] = newptr;
    }
    // check for insertion at tail
    else
    {
        node* predptr = first[key];
        while(1)
        {
            // insert at tail
            if (predptr->next == NULL)
            {
                predptr->next = newptr;
                break;
            }

            // update pointer
            predptr = predptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

**Q:**
I want to know how to print values I have stored in this hash table program.

Comment: BTW `strcpy(newptr->word/* maybe name */, buffer);` : You need to allocate a copy destination area to `name` before this.

Comment: start with `void print(node *np){ while(np){ printf("%s->", np->name); np = np->next; } printf("Nil\n"); }`

Comment: `int main(char* name)` is not a correct declaration of the `main()` function.

Comment: What is the `names` array for?

Comment: Function definition must be above `main()` to use inside `main()` or try to declare function prototype above `main()`.